# What is the cause of this panic?

Tags: go

I am fairly new to Go, could someone help me diagnose this problem.

```
type ValidationStatus struct {
    Passed bool
    Errors map[string]*ValidationError
}

// ...

status := ValidationStatus{Passed: true}

// ...

status.Passed = false
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(typeField.Name)) // string
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(validationError)) // *validation.ValidationError   
status.Errors[typeField.Name] = validationError // Panic triggered here.
```

`validationError` is defined in the validation package. This code is in the same file as the struct.

This is the first time I have hit an issue like this, I think I may be using the map incorrectly but then I don't understand why this wouldn't cause a compile error so maybe a type issue? Any pointers to solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, if you're asking about a panic then make sure to include the actual panic message.

Comment: See: https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action for an introduction to maps in Go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't tell us what the error message was!

> [Map types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)
>
> A new, empty map value is made using the built-in function make, which
>   takes the map type and an optional capacity hint as arguments:
>
> ```
> make(map[string]int)
> make(map[string]int, 100)
> ```

For example,

```
status := ValidationStatus{Passed: true, Errors: make(map[string]*ValidationError)}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your map is `nil`. You simply need to initialize it. This is why most object initialization is hidden behind a function:

```
status := ValidationStatus{Passed: true, Errors: make(map[string]*ValidationError)}
```

..or, behind a function:

```
status := NewValidationStatus()

// ...

func NewValidationStatus() ValidationStatus {
    return ValidationStatus{
        Passed: true,
        Errors: make(map[string]*ValidationError),
    }
}
```

<kbd>[See it on the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/jlb1uvnu-J)</kbd>